# Finding common breaks for multiple variables

Tags: r, histogram

Supposed I have a `data.frame` with a variables:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(s=rnorm(100))
```

And then two other variables that are monotonous with the first one:

```
df$p <- pnorm(abs(df$s),lower.tail=F)
df$q <- p.adjust(df$p,method="BH")
```

I'd like to produce `breaks` for `df$s` and know which values of `df$p` and `df$a` correspond to these `breaks`.

So if I do:

```
s.breaks <- hist(df$s,breaks=10,plot=F)$breaks
```

what would be the values of `df$p` and `df$q` corresponding to `s.breaks`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the categories that your histogram function created using `findInterval`.

```
df$cats <- findInterval(df$s, s.breaks)
```

Here is the structure of the histogram

```
s.hist <- hist(df$s,breaks=10,plot=F)
str(s.hist)
List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:11] -2.5 -2 -1.5 -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 ...
 $ counts  : int [1:10] 1 3 7 14 21 20 19 9 4 2
 $ density : num [1:10] 0.02 0.06 0.14 0.28 0.42 0.4 0.38 0.18 0.08 0.04
 $ mids    : num [1:10] -2.25 -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25
 $ xname   : chr "df$s"
 $ equidist: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Note the elements of the counts variable. This is identical to the output of `table` on df$cats.

```
table(df$cats)

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  3  7 14 21 20 19  9  4  2
```

---

If the goal is to then use the categories constructed by df$cats to perform calculations. Then you are done. For example,

`tapply(df$p, df["cats"], mean)`
will calculate the mean of df$b for the observations contained in each histogram bar from your question.

If the goal is to construct categories for the other variables that have the same number of counts within corresponding category cells, you could use `rank` together with `cumsum` and `findInterval` like this.

```
df$catp <- findInterval(rank(df$p), cumsum(c(1, s.hist$counts, 1)))
```

You can check that the cell counts line up again with `table`.

```
table(df$catp)

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  3  7 14 21 20 19  9  4  2
```

Comment: And then linearly extrapolate what would be the equivalent values of df$b and df$c for a.breaks?

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Do you want to construct histograms for b and c that has the same shape as a?  or do you want to use the breaks in cat to separate b and c into groups?

Comment: I want to find the values of b and c that correspond to a.breaks. For example, what's the value of b and c that correspond to a=-2.5 (a.breaks[1]). So I think the first option you mention is close to what I ant.

Comment: Sorry I should edit my post to add that b and c are monotonous with a